# Android application - 'Active Installs by Country' shows countries that application is not available in

Tags: android

I've got a free Android Application that is currently available only in European Union countries (Done via the developer console). However, when I view the 'Active Device Installs by Country' statistics for the application, it shows the application is installed in countries that I have not made it available - e.g. India. Why would this be?